# Spring pre-authentication with Webflux

Tags: spring-security, spring-webflux

I have just built a springboot3 reactive web application and now I want to add security to make it work with our in house aunthentication stack.

For another web-mvc application we do this by adding a `AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter` to the HttpSecurity.

Now I'd like to do the same for my reactive application but I don't find any example or documentation on how to do this.